# Character not saving to array

Tags: c, cs50

I am asking the user to input a string. I would like to output the first letter of each word in uppercase.

**Example:**
`barack hussein obama` => `BHO`

Currently this is my attempt:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void){
    string user_name = GetString();

    int word_counter = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    // Get length of string.
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(user_name); i++){
        if(strncmp(&user_name[i], " ", 1) == 0){
            word_counter += 1;
        }
    }
    word_counter += 1;


    // Declare empty array and size.
    char output[word_counter];

    // Iterate through array to assign first characters to new array.
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(user_name); i++){
        if(i == 0){
            output[counter] = toupper(user_name[i]);
            counter += 1;
        }
        else if(strcmp(&user_name[i - 1], " ") == 0){
            output[counter] = toupper(user_name[i]);
            counter += 1;
        }
    }

    // Output result.
    for(int i = 0; i < word_counter; i++){
        printf("%c\n", output[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

When the output returns, I only receive `B`. It seems that output is not saving the first letters of each word. Am I declaring output incorrectly?

Comment: `strncmp(&user_name[i], " ", 1) == 0` is more simply written as `username[i] == ' '`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strcmp(&user_name[i - 1], " ")` Is not just comparing 1 char as inteneded (like your original `strncmp(&user_name[i], " ", 1)` does).

Why use str[n]cmp() anyway, why not just `if (name[i] == ' ') { ...` ?

Comment: I am trying to compare the last character. If the name is `Barack Hussein Obama`, I would like to ask if the character before the `H` and the `O` have empty space. If so, I'll know it's the beginning of the word.

Comment: @rebbailey That's just the problem, `strcmp` means to compare entire string, whereas you in fact only want to compare one character.